# Parameters - Unable to resolve combinations of multiple mandatory or non-mandatory groupings

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that has 5 parameters.  I don't want the script to run without any parameters, `.\script.ps1`

Parameters [1|2|3] can be used independently or together with one or both of the others.  [4|5] can be used together or alone but must be used with one or more of [1|2|3].

```
.\script.ps1 -1
.\script.ps1 -2 -3
.\script.ps1 -1 -4
.\script.ps1 -3 -4 -5
```

I've tried using multiple of ParameterSetName and can set [1|2|3] as Mandatory for [4|5] but I don't want all to be mandatory, only "at least" one.

This was a quickly aborted attempt as I quickly lost how I could keep it all straight.

```
function testt {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'All')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerAndDays', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NonInteractiveAndDays', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All')]
        [int]$Days,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerAndDisabled', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NonInteractiveAndDisabled', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All')]
        [switch]$Disabled,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerAndInvalid', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NonInteractiveAndInvalid', Mandatory=$True)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All')]
        [switch]$Invalid,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerAndDays')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerAndDisabled')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ComputerAndInvalid')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All')]
        [string]$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NonInteractiveAndDays')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NonInteractiveAndDisabled')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='NonInteractiveAndInvalid')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='All')]
        [switch]$NonInteractive
    )
}
```

I finally settled on this workaround (full script [here](https://github.com/skoliver1/ProfileRemover/blob/main/ProfileRemover.ps1))

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False)]
param(
    [switch]$NonInteractive,

    [string]$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

    [int]$Days,

    [switch]$Disabled,

    [switch]$Invalid
)

If ( $NonInteractive -and -not($Days -or $Disabled -or $Invalid) ) {
}

If ( $Computer -and -not($Days -or $Disabled -or $Invalid) ) {
}
```

but I don't like it since the syntax help doesn't give any help as to my usage intentions.

```
SYNTAX
    testt [-NonInteractive] [-Computer <string>] [-Days <int>] [-Disabled] [-Invalid]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want all of these:

    `.\test -Days $i`   

    `.\test -Days $i -Disabled`
    `.\test -Days $i -Invalid`
    `.\test -Days $i -Disabled Invalid`
    `.\test -Disabled`
    `.\test -Disabled -Invalid`
    `.\test -Invalid`

being valid, plus `-Computer` and `-NonInteractive` as optional for any of those combinations, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dynamic parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters?view=powershell-5.1#dynamic-parameters)

Comment: I can see how this could be helpful in certain scenarios, but I don't see how I can adapt it to my situation.  I could add a mandatory var `[-IsRemote <True|False>]` which then dynamically adds the `-Computer` and then another mandatory `[-IsInteractive <True|False>]` but I don't know how to make it mandatory that *at least one* other parameter is provided, whether it be `-Days`, `-Invalid` or `-Disabled`.  If I mark all as mandatory, they must all be provided.  Mark only `-Days` and then that must always be provided, which I don't want.